# How to obtain the top five objects from an array by popularity

Tags: javascript

Description:

The `getMostPopularAuthors` returns an array containing five objects or fewer, that represent the most popular authors whose books have been checked out the most. Popularity is represented by finding all of the books written by the author and then adding up the number of times those books have been borrowed.

The function has two parameters, in the following order:

- An array of books.
- An array of authors.

Each object in the returned array has two keys:

- The `name` key which represents the first and last name of the author.
- The `count` key which represents the number of times the author's books have been borrowed.

If more than five authors are present, only the top five should be returned.

Note:

I can solve the second part of the answer, but **I am struggling with the first part**. I know it wants to access the `author.js` file but it also wants to access the `books.js` file as well and I cant figure out how to implement and access the `author.js` data.

Here is a portion of the `author.js` file data:

```
const authors = [
{
id: 0,
name: {
  first: "Lucia",
  last: "Moreno",
},
},
{
id: 1,
name: {
  first: "Trisha",
  last: "Mathis",
},
},
{
id: 2,
name: {
  first: "Arnold",
  last: "Marks",
},
},
{
id: 3,
name: {
  first: "Faye",
  last: "Arnold",
},
},
{
id: 4,
name: {
  first: "Tami",
  last: "Hurst",
},
},
{
id: 5,
name: {
  first: "Farmer",
  last: "Stevenson",
},
},
{
id: 6,
name: {
  first: "Hancock",
  last: "Fuller",
},
},
{
id: 7,
name: {
  first: "Ila",
  last: "Reid",
},
},
{
id: 8,
name: {
  first: "Susanne",
  last: "Lawson",
},
}
]
```

Here is a portion of the `book.js` file data:

```
const books = [
{
id: "5f447132d487bd81da01e25e",
title: "sit eiusmod occaecat eu magna",
genre: "Science",
authorId: 8,
borrows: [
  {
    id: "5f446f2e2cfa3e1d234679b9",
    returned: false,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e1c71888e2233621e",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ede05a0b1e3394d8b",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ea6b68cf6f85f6e28",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eed18105706d6ca19",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e91c2af00cb74e82b",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e5aa2bb5545a0f8a6",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ea508b6a99c3e42c6",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e0b3e2ff72fc503e7",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e91c2af00cb74e82b",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e2f35653fa80bf490",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e7b9cd304fed3a8bc",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ed9aac23c0340aab2",
    returned: true,
  },
],
},
{
id: "5f4471329627160be1e8ce92",
title: "esse ea veniam non occaecat",
genre: "Classics",
authorId: 10,
borrows: [
  {
    id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
    returned: false,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ec32d71dabec35b06",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e7a1be21e362b82f9",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ec32d71dabec35b06",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e59f9380a1d03d766",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e141b97d842b680fd",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ee176f80b8d5d24da",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eef419207c5fa4ec9",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
    returned: true,
  },
],
},
{
id: "5f44713265e5d8d17789beb0",
title: "tempor occaecat fugiat",
genre: "Travel",
authorId: 16,
borrows: [
  {
    id: "5f446f2e4eff1030e7316861",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ecc5c4787c403f844",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ee1661e64cde14e55",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e3e70bb4e1ab821c9",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e136866e4fe60c893",
    returned: true,
  },
],
},
]
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
function getMostPopularAuthors(books, authors) {
const authorPopularity = books.map((book) => book.authorId);
const temp = [];
authorPopularity.map((authorId) => {
const borrowLocation = temp.findIndex((element) => element.name === authorId);
if (borrowLocation >= 0) {
  temp[borrowLocation].count = temp[borrowLocation].count + 1;
} else {
  temp.push({ name: authorId, count: 1 });
}
});
temp.sort((alpha, delta) => delta.count - alpha.count);
if (temp.length > 5) {
return temp.slice(0, 5);
}
return temp;
}
```

Also if anyone would like the testing code for reference it is here:

```
describe("getMostPopularAuthors()", () => {
it("should return an ordered list of most popular authors", () => {
  const actual = getMostPopularAuthors(books, authors);
  const [first, second] = [
    { name: "Susanne Lawson", count: 11 },
    { name: "Matthews Sanders", count: 5 },
  ];
  expect(actual[0]).to.eql(first);
  expect(actual[1]).to.eql(second);
});

it("should limit the list to the top five", () => {
  const actual = getMostPopularAuthors(books, authors);
  expect(actual.length).to.equal(5);
});});});
```

Comment: Tried to edit this as best as I could, please edit further to make it easier to understand your actual "problem"

Comment: You are using the .map() function but you are not returning nothing. Use forEach() instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer to my question in case anyone needs closure:

```
function getMostPopularAuthors(books,authors) {
const topAuthors = authors.map(a => ({
...a,
// books: books.filter(b => b.authorId === a.id),
bookCount: books.filter(b => b.authorId === a.id).length,
borrowCount: books.filter(b => b.authorId === a.id).reduce((acc, cur)
=> acc + cur.borrows.length, 0)
})).sort((b, a) => a.borrowCount - b.borrowCount);
topAuthors.length = 5;
return topAuthors.map(ta => {
return {count: ta.borrowCount, name: ta.name.first + " " + ta.name.last};
// return {id: ta.id, name: `${ta.name.first} ${ta.name.last}`};
})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map() the author array and using filter(), find all the books by that author. For count, you can use reduce to add together the length of each authors borrows array.

```
function getPopularAuthors(authorArray, booksArray, total) {
  return authorArray.map(a => {
    // loop through the author array
    a.count = booksArray.filter(b => b.authorId === a.id).reduce((b, a) => b + (a.borrows && a.borrows.length || 0), 0);
    // to get the count, filter the book array and then reduce it to a sum of all matching books borrows array length
    a.name = `${a.name.first} ${a.name.last}`;
    delete a.id
    // remove the id since that isn't part of the desired result
    return a
  }).sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count).slice(0, total)
  // sort the end result to be biggest counts first, then slice the array down to the desired length
}
```

```js
const authors = [{
    id: 0,
    name: {
      first: "Lucia",
      last: "Moreno",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: {
      first: "Trisha",
      last: "Mathis",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: {
      first: "Arnold",
      last: "Marks",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: {
      first: "Faye",
      last: "Arnold",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: {
      first: "Tami",
      last: "Hurst",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: {
      first: "Farmer",
      last: "Stevenson",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    name: {
      first: "Hancock",
      last: "Fuller",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: {
      first: "Ila",
      last: "Reid",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: {
      first: "Susanne",
      last: "Lawson",
    },
  }
]

const books = [{
    id: "test",
    title: "Test with no borrows",
    genre: "Science",
    authorId: 8},
    {
    id: "5f447132d487bd81da01e25e",
    title: "sit eiusmod occaecat eu magna",
    genre: "Science",
    authorId: 8,
    borrows: [{
        id: "5f446f2e2cfa3e1d234679b9",
        returned: false,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e1c71888e2233621e",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ede05a0b1e3394d8b",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ea6b68cf6f85f6e28",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eed18105706d6ca19",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e91c2af00cb74e82b",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e5aa2bb5545a0f8a6",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ea508b6a99c3e42c6",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e0b3e2ff72fc503e7",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e91c2af00cb74e82b",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e2f35653fa80bf490",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e7b9cd304fed3a8bc",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ed9aac23c0340aab2",
        returned: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "5f4471329627160be1e8ce92",
    title: "esse ea veniam non occaecat",
    genre: "Classics",
    authorId: 10,
    borrows: [{
        id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
        returned: false,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ec32d71dabec35b06",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e7a1be21e362b82f9",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ec32d71dabec35b06",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e59f9380a1d03d766",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e141b97d842b680fd",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ee176f80b8d5d24da",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eef419207c5fa4ec9",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
        returned: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "5f44713265e5d8d17789beb0",
    title: "tempor occaecat fugiat",
    genre: "Travel",
    authorId: 16,
    borrows: [{
        id: "5f446f2e4eff1030e7316861",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ecc5c4787c403f844",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ee1661e64cde14e55",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e3e70bb4e1ab821c9",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e136866e4fe60c893",
        returned: true,
      },
    ],
  }
]

function getPopularAuthors(authorArray, booksArray, total) {
  return authorArray.map(a => {
    a.count = booksArray.filter(b => b.authorId === a.id).reduce((b, a) => b + (a.borrows && a.borrows.length || 0), 0);
    a.name = `${a.name.first} ${a.name.last}`;
    delete a.id;
    return a;
  }).sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count).slice(0, total)
}

console.log(getPopularAuthors(authors, books, 5))
```

Comment: I tried that code up above and it sends back a type error that it Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: TYpo: `b.count = a.count` should be `b.count - a.count`. I don't think that will fix the error that @javanoob is getting though.

Comment: yeah fixing the typo still results in the typeError

Comment: @javanoob - sorry, I assumed borrows would exist on all objects. I added in a conditional to my answer so it won't error out.

Comment: I also amended the sort typo

Comment: I attempted the code with the conditional and it gives me a syntax error now when using the '?' conditional

Comment: Interesting bc it didn't error in the snippet. I replaced it with a different way of testing that borrows exists. Let me know if this works, answer revised.

Comment: I tried it this way and for the first part it returns:
for should return an ordered list of most popular authors:
Error: expected { Object (title, genre, ...) } to deeply equal { name: 'Susanne Lawson', count: 11 }
should limit the list to the top five:
error expected 9 to equal 5

Comment: ok. I did find a typo in my function - fixed - and added the name fix. Can you pls test again. Code fixed in header and snippet.

Comment: i tried that one and still gives TypeError: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
const getMostPopularAuthors = (authors, books, max = 5) => {
  const countPerAuthor = books.reduce((acc, { authorId, borrows = [] }) => {
    acc[authorId] = (acc[authorId] || 0) + borrows.length;
    return acc;
  }, {})
  const authorsByPopularity = Object.entries(countPerAuthor).sort(([, popA], [, popB]) => popB - popA).map(([authorId]) => Number(authorId));
  const topAuthors = authorsByPopularity.slice(0, max);
  return authors.filter(({ id }) => topAuthors.includes(id)).map(({ id, name }) => ({
    name: `${name.first} ${name.last}`,
    count: countPerAuthor[id]
  }));
};
```

```js
const getMostPopularAuthors = (authors, books, max = 5) => {
  const countPerAuthor = books.reduce((acc, {
    authorId,
    borrows = []
  }) => {
    acc[authorId] = (acc[authorId] || 0) + borrows.length;
    return acc;
  }, {})
  const authorsByPopularity = Object.entries(countPerAuthor).sort(([, popA], [, popB]) => popB - popA).map(([authorId]) => Number(authorId));
  const topAuthors = authorsByPopularity.slice(0, max);
  return authors.filter(({
    id
  }) => topAuthors.includes(id)).map(({
    id,
    name
  }) => ({
    name: `${name.first} ${name.last}`,
    count: countPerAuthor[id]
  }));
};
const authors = [{
    id: 0,
    name: {
      first: "Lucia",
      last: "Moreno",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: {
      first: "Trisha",
      last: "Mathis",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: {
      first: "Arnold",
      last: "Marks",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: {
      first: "Faye",
      last: "Arnold",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: {
      first: "Tami",
      last: "Hurst",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: {
      first: "Farmer",
      last: "Stevenson",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: {
      first: "Hancock",
      last: "Fuller",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: {
      first: "Ila",
      last: "Reid",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: {
      first: "Susanne",
      last: "Lawson",
    },
  }
];
const books = [{
    id: "5f447132d487bd81da01e25e",
    title: "sit eiusmod occaecat eu magna",
    genre: "Science",
    authorId: 8,
    borrows: [{
        id: "5f446f2e2cfa3e1d234679b9",
        returned: false,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e1c71888e2233621e",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ede05a0b1e3394d8b",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ea6b68cf6f85f6e28",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eed18105706d6ca19",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e91c2af00cb74e82b",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e5aa2bb5545a0f8a6",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ea508b6a99c3e42c6",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e0b3e2ff72fc503e7",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e91c2af00cb74e82b",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e2f35653fa80bf490",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e7b9cd304fed3a8bc",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ed9aac23c0340aab2",
        returned: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "5f4471329627160be1e8ce92",
    title: "esse ea veniam non occaecat",
    genre: "Classics",
    authorId: 10,
    borrows: [{
        id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
        returned: false,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ec32d71dabec35b06",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e7a1be21e362b82f9",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ec32d71dabec35b06",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e59f9380a1d03d766",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e141b97d842b680fd",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ee176f80b8d5d24da",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eef419207c5fa4ec9",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
        returned: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "5f44713265e5d8d17789beb0",
    title: "tempor occaecat fugiat",
    genre: "Travel",
    authorId: 16,
    borrows: [{
        id: "5f446f2e4eff1030e7316861",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ecc5c4787c403f844",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ee1661e64cde14e55",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e3e70bb4e1ab821c9",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e136866e4fe60c893",
        returned: true,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const top5 = getMostPopularAuthors(authors, books, 5);
console.log(top5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a helper function to get the author by id and used explicit logic to obtain the desired results:

```
function getAuthor(authors, authorId) {
    for (let author of authors) {
        if (author.id === authorId) return author;
    }
    return null;
}

function getMostPopularAuthors(authors, books) {
    let borrowMap = {};
    let bookBorrows = [];
    for (let book of books) {
        let borrows = book.borrows.length;
        if (!borrowMap[book.authorId]) {
            borrowMap[book.authorId] = bookBorrows.length;
            bookBorrows.push({authorId: book.authorId, borrows});
        } else {
            bookBorrows[borrowMap[book.authorId]].borrows += borrows;
        }
    }
    bookBorrows = bookBorrows.filter(item => (getAuthor(authors, item.authorId) !== null))
    bookBorrows.sort(function(a, b) {
        a.borrows >= b.borrows;
    });
    let output = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < bookBorrows.length; index++) output.push(getAuthor(authors, bookBorrows[index].authorId));
    return output;
}
```

We iterate books, compute the number of borrows, use a mapping array to ease our indexing task, filter from borrows those which do not have a corresponding author, sort the result descendingly by borrow number and then compute the output.

Result:

[image]

The input had three books, from which only one had a corresponding author, so the result is quite expected.

```js
const authors = [
{
id: 0,
name: {
  first: "Lucia",
  last: "Moreno",
},
},
{
id: 1,
name: {
  first: "Trisha",
  last: "Mathis",
},
},
{
id: 2,
name: {
  first: "Arnold",
  last: "Marks",
},
},
{
id: 3,
name: {
  first: "Faye",
  last: "Arnold",
},
},
{
id: 4,
name: {
  first: "Tami",
  last: "Hurst",
},
},
{
id: 5,
name: {
  first: "Farmer",
  last: "Stevenson",
},
},
{
id: 6,
name: {
  first: "Hancock",
  last: "Fuller",
},
},
{
id: 7,
name: {
  first: "Ila",
  last: "Reid",
},
},
{
id: 8,
name: {
  first: "Susanne",
  last: "Lawson",
},
}
];

const books = [
{
id: "5f447132d487bd81da01e25e",
title: "sit eiusmod occaecat eu magna",
genre: "Science",
authorId: 8,
borrows: [
  {
    id: "5f446f2e2cfa3e1d234679b9",
    returned: false,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e1c71888e2233621e",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ede05a0b1e3394d8b",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ea6b68cf6f85f6e28",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eed18105706d6ca19",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e91c2af00cb74e82b",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e5aa2bb5545a0f8a6",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ea508b6a99c3e42c6",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e0b3e2ff72fc503e7",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e91c2af00cb74e82b",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e2f35653fa80bf490",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e7b9cd304fed3a8bc",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ed9aac23c0340aab2",
    returned: true,
  },
],
},
{
id: "5f4471329627160be1e8ce92",
title: "esse ea veniam non occaecat",
genre: "Classics",
authorId: 10,
borrows: [
  {
    id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
    returned: false,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ec32d71dabec35b06",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e7a1be21e362b82f9",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ec32d71dabec35b06",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e59f9380a1d03d766",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e141b97d842b680fd",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ee176f80b8d5d24da",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eef419207c5fa4ec9",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
    returned: true,
  },
],
},
{
id: "5f44713265e5d8d17789beb0",
title: "tempor occaecat fugiat",
genre: "Travel",
authorId: 16,
borrows: [
  {
    id: "5f446f2e4eff1030e7316861",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ecc5c4787c403f844",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ee1661e64cde14e55",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e3e70bb4e1ab821c9",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e136866e4fe60c893",
    returned: true,
  },
],
},
]

function getAuthor(authors, authorId) {
    for (let author of authors) {
        if (author.id === authorId) return author;
    }
    return null;
}

function getMostPopularAuthors(authors, books) {
    let borrowMap = {};
    let bookBorrows = [];
    for (let book of books) {
        let borrows = book.borrows.length;
        if (!borrowMap[book.authorId]) {
            borrowMap[book.authorId] = bookBorrows.length;
            bookBorrows.push({authorId: book.authorId, borrows});
        } else {
            bookBorrows[borrowMap[book.authorId]].borrows += borrows;
        }
    }
    bookBorrows = bookBorrows.filter(item => (getAuthor(authors, item.authorId) !== null))
    bookBorrows.sort(function(a, b) {
        a.borrows >= b.borrows;
    });
    let output = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < bookBorrows.length; index++) output.push(getAuthor(authors, bookBorrows[index].authorId));
    return output;
}

console.log(getMostPopularAuthors(authors, books));
```

Comment: doing this just results in a Type error that it Cannot read property 'length' of undefined for  let borrows= book.borrow.length

Comment: @javanoob I factually know that this works, I have actually tested the code. I suppose that you did not add your objects. Adding a snippet to the answer to prove my point.

Comment: @javanoob I have added a snippet to my question where the input is properly initialized and the very same code as in the original answer is in use. It works.

Comment: the only thing is that there isnt just 3 inputs for books I only included a portion of the data because there are 50+ book inputs

Comment: @javanoob can you properly initialize your full book sets and test my answer on them?

Comment: okay sorry for delayed response but I tried that and i received errors 

should return an ordered list of most popular authors:
expected { Object (id, name) } to deeply equal { name: 'Susanne Lawson', count: 11 }


should limit the list to the top five:

expected 8 to equal 5

Comment: @javanoob I do not understand your point. Can you create a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem? The actual input you have was not given in the question, so it's difficult to fix something if we do not have basic information about him. If you provide further information, then I'm happy to help.